# Resetting the conditional variable (boost)

Tags: c++, synchronization, boost-thread

I apologize if this question is already asked.
Is it possible to clear the conditional variable which is already set?
The details on what I want to achieve below:

```
void worker_thread {
    while (wait_for_conditional_variable_execute) {
        // process data here
        // Inform main thread that the data got processed
        // Clear the conditional variable 'execute'
    }
}
```

NOTE that **The worker thread should process the data only one time, and it should wait for main thread to set "execute" conditional variable again**

I also thought about having a flag like below

```
void worker_thread {
    while (wait_for_conditional_variable_execute) {
        if (flag) { flag = 0; }
        // process data here. The `flag` will be set by main thread
        }
}
```

But I am thinking this would be CPU intensive as this is nothing but polling of the flag. Isn't so?

Comment: I missed to mention few more details such as    
_1. I cannot create new thread every time once the job is finished.  
2. There are 100s of threads to manage, hence, polling of the flag will not be acceptible_

Comment: Just to clarify, as you've tagged this with [tag:boost-thread], can I assume you're using a version of C++ lower than C++11, and thus are using `boost::thread` and `boost::condition_variable`?

Comment: @Tas, yes.. i am using C++... just FYI, I am yet to decide between `boost::thread` or `QThread` (since it is a QT project). But I would definitely use `boost::condition_variable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The `condition_variable` is reset any time `wait()` is called. `wait()` blocks the current thread until the `condition_variable` is *woken up* so to speak.

You appear to be using the `condition_variable` incorrectly, however. Instead of saying

```
while (wait_for_conditional_variable_execute)
```

You really wanna say

```
while (thread_should_run)
{
    // wait_for_conditional_variable_execute
    cv.wait();
}
```

This would give you something to the following effect:

```
void processDataThread()
{
    while (processData)
    {
        // Wait to be given data to process
        cv.wait();
        // Finished waiting, so retrieve data to process
        int n = getData();
        // Process data:
        total += n;
    }
}
```

Then in your main thread you'd have:

```
addData(16);
cv.notify_all();
```

Your thread will process the data, re-enter the `while` loop then wait for the `condition_variable` to be triggered. Once triggered (i.e. `notify()` is called) the thread will process the data, then wait again.

Comment: Thanks @Tas.. it worked!!.. glad that I posted this query here!! Cheers!!